# Timestamp inherent data must be provided panics on Seedling runtime

Tags: parachain, runtime, parachain-collator

I have built a basic setup of a local Rococo-relay chain and 2 collators to run the Seedling runtime:
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/cumulus/parachains/runtimes/starters/seedling

Both collators panic with "Timestamp inherent data must be provided " when the seedling is onboarded. Tried both with zombienet and by running the nodes myself.

Only change I made to default Seedling chain-spec was to change from `westend` to `rococo-local` on `relay_chain`.

Any fix you can think about? Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide exact instructions to reproduce?